# manipulating json data in java...java newbie

Tags: java, json

I'm learning java at the moment and building a small app in Kafka Streams to ingest data and create a new stream essentially.

I have a main class like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

        streamsConfiguration.put("application.id", "streams-consumer-logs");
        streamsConfiguration.put("client.id", "consumer-client");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class);
        streamsConfiguration.put("servers");


        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

        System.out.println(streamsConfiguration);


        final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream( stringSerde, stringSerde,"sdp_logs");


        //textLines.print();
        System.out.println("test");



        KStream<String, String> wordCounts = textLines
                .map((key, value) ->  {
                    //how do I manipulate this value which is a json object?
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(value);

                    FilterLogs filterlogs = new FilterLogs(json);

                    String filterlogs = filterlogs.execute();

                    return KeyValue.pair(key, json);
                });

        //KStream<String, Long> streamWrite = wordCounts.toStream();

        wordCounts.print();


        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfiguration);

        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();


        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }

}
```

I then have a `FilterLogs` class that looks like this:

```
public class FilterLogs {

    private type? jsoonObj;

    public FilterLogs (type? jsonObj) {
        this.jsonObj = jsonObj;
    }


    public type? getResult() { return result; }


    public void execute () {

        //manipulation of jsonObj goes in here?

        }
    }

}
```

My json object looks like this that `value` returns             `KStream<String, String> wordCounts = textLines.map((key, value) ->  {}`:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "dgtl"
  ], 
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host1", 
    "name": "host`", 
    "version": "5.4.1"
  }, 
  "input_type": "log", 
  "@timestamp": "2017-09-27T20:01:52.282Z", 
  "source": "/log/state-change.log", 
  "offset": 1725163, 
  "message": "message of the log is here"
  "type": "log"
}
```

From my understanding in Java (as I come from the a functional programming paradigm) is that I have to take `value`, pass it to the class `FilterLogs` in my case, and then that class should return the new `value`...right?

Where I'm confused is what type to use for the class and how do I actually parse through the json and do stuff with it?

Normally, in javascript, I can just parse through it with a bunch of loops and do what I want but I don't quite get how to do this in Java.

What if I want my json object to return like this?

```
{
  "tags": [
    "dgtl"
  ], 
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host1"
  }, 
  "offset": 1725163, 
  "message": "message of the log is here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the new

1. JSON-P( for JSON processing & parsing) - http://json-b.net/
2. JSON-B (for JSON Binding) apis that was released recently - https://github.com/javaee/jsonp

They were made purposely for all of your usecases